# Expected ), but I couldn't understand the syntax issue here

Tags: jquery

[image]

Anybody plz find out the issue here...

```
SelectedPanelIds="";
        var PanelIds='@Model.srPanelList';
        var arrPanelList =PanelIds.split('|');
        for(var i = 0;i<(arrPanelList.length)-1;i++)
        {
            var Id = arrPanelList[i].split('~');
            if (Id[1] != @Model.ObjectId)
            {
               SelectedPanelIds = SelectedPanelIds + Id[1] +',' ;
            }
       }
```

Showing  Expected ), but i couldn't understand the issue.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, could you please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Part of an MCVE is listing the code **itself**, rather than an image containing it -- people aren't going to want to type out your code manually! ;)

Comment: Instead of splitting and joining, why don't you use replace?

Comment: share the generated javascript

Comment: Change `if (Id[1] != @Model.ObjectId)` to `if (Id[1] != '@Model.ObjectId')`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a syntax error.

You have `@Model.ObjectId` but you probably want to wrap that in quotes.

So your `if` statement would look like:

```
if (Id[1] != '@Model.ObjectId') {
    // ...
```